# angular.constant like an object take same ref

Tags: angularjs

Why if I define a constant object like

```
app.constant('TEST', { title: 'Hello' });
```

and I make this in controller

```
var x = TEST;
x.title = 'Hello World';
console.log(TEST);
```

The value of constant has been change?? I read angular's doc and it says that constant cannot change their value.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the constant can't be changed if it is a primitive value (ie, 1, true, "appName"). However it is an issue with Angular 1.x that if the constant is an object, it's properties remain assignable. Semantically, yes, we would expect these values to never change, but the framework is not doing any wrapping of the provided object to prevent a developer from mutating it.

You can read a bit more here:
http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/